# Matplotlib FuncAnimation combined with event handler ignores some mouseclicks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a small matplotlib tool which loops through a set of frames, and should respond to some keyboard and mouse events. However, some of my button_press_events are ignored, and I don't understand why. Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
framecounter = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '')

def on_click(event):
    print event.xdata

def func(i):
    framecounter.set_text(str(i))
    return framecounter,

def toggle_pause(event):
    if event.key.isspace():
        if anim.running:
            anim.event_source.stop()
        else:
            anim.event_source.start()
        anim.running ^= True

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func, 100)
anim.running = True
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_pause)

plt.show()
```

I'm not sure whether the play/pause functionality is related to the problem, but it helps to reproduce the problem.

It seems that my button_press_events are ignored if they occur immediately after I pause the animation. The second press always prints output, and if I first move the mouse or wait a few seconds before clicking, it also prints output.

What is happening here?

I tried it on different systems with mpl2.1.1 and mpl2.2.2 with TKAgg and QT4Agg.

Comment: I just tried it with mpl2.2.2 / QT4Agg and I cannot reproduce this. All clicks are recorded in the console.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think it might be related to a time lag. If I keep moving my mouse over the figure while pressing the space bar, it freezes briefly. Perhaps my computer is a bit slow...